# Is there a way to resolve this linking problem with DuckX

Tags: c++

I've had several issues with the DuckX library, and now I can't quite make it work. I get this error whenever I try to run the example code from their GitHub [page](https://github.com/amiremohamadi/DuckX).

```
undefined reference to 'duckx::Document::Document(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::alocator<char> >)'
```

When I run the code without the .docx in the constructor I don't get that error.

```
duckx::Document doc();//works
duckx::Document doc("file.docx");//doesn't work
```

I run the code like this:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -L "DuckX\build\Debug" -lduckx -I "DuckX/include" -I "DuckX/thirdparty/pugixml" -I "DuckX/thirdparty/zip" -D_SSIZE_T
```

Comment: What version of g++ are you running? Could you try compiling again but adding the flag `--std=c++11` (or 14 or 17, if your g++ version is recent enough?)

Comment: @TylerStoney I'm running 6.3.0. I've compiled the code with the suggested flag but I get the same error.

Comment: please don't re-ask questions, you can edit your original question instead